# Testing an infinite sequence with NUnit, but only a finite sequence must be checked

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

I have an Extension Method that extract the numbers in a list of strings (bbb1, da21ds, dsa231djsla90 ==> 1, 21, 23190):

```
    public static int[] GetContainedNumbers(this string[] source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        int[] result = new int[] {};
        
        foreach (var s in source)
        {
            string onlyNumbers = new String(s.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(onlyNumbers)) throw new ArgumentException();
            int extractedNumber = Int32.Parse(onlyNumbers);
            
            result = result.Concat(new int[] { extractedNumber }).ToArray();
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

I need to make a test with NUnit. The request is to make a test with an infinite sequence of strings (a1z, a2z, a3z, ...), but the output only needs to check the first 100 numbers.

Currently I have no idea what I'm supposed to do. My starting idea was to create a test like this:

```
        int[] expectedResult = Enumerable.Range(0, 99).ToArray();
        string[] source = new string[] {};
        int n = 0;
        
        while (true)
        {
            if (n == 99) break;
            source = source.Concat(new string[] { "a" + n + "z" }).ToArray();
            n++;
        }
        
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, source.GetContainedNumbers());
```

But it doesn't really make sense since the array is finite and not infinite.
I don't know what it means to create an infinite list of things and how I should create it nor testing it.

I can edit the Extension Method if needed. Thanks in advance for any help and sorry if my english is quite broken.

---

The first task is to make the Extension method itself, which I have resolved above. It can be modified, but it must resolve this piece of code (which I can't edit):

```
foreach (var d in new[] { "1qui7", "q8u8o", "-1024", "0q0ua0" }.GetContainedNumbers())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, ", d);
            var strings = new [ ] { "1qui7" , " q8u8o " , " −1024" , " 0 q0ua0 " };
        }
```

Expected output: 17, 88, 1024, 0,

Comment: Hint: The way to create an infinite sequence is to use [recursion](https://code-maze.com/csharp-basics-recursion/).

Comment: It sounds like the task is basically infeasible - precisely because an array always has a finite size. I suggest you go back to whoever set you the task.

Comment: @NightOwl888: The array itself can't be infinite. There are plenty of ways of creating an infinite `IEnumerable<string>` - and I wouldn't personally use recursion - but given that the parameter type is `string[]`, the task that has been set doesn't make sense.

Comment: If this is production code and not just a coding challenge I would just test on an unreasonably large number, but given that you pass it a `string[]` it will never get an infinite object

Comment: @JonSkeet - I know. But I don't see any requirement that this must be done with an array. `IEnumerable<string>` is also a good suggestion.

Comment: If the test is to be done for only first 100 results, then any input which can generate 101 result should be considered as infinite. And if you really have an infinite collection, how are you planning to get out of the loop and return from the method?

Comment: I have updated the original answer with the first task requested by the exercise. The test is required to run with the method implemented according to the first task provided.

Comment: Obviously you can't actually create an infinite sequence of strings that contain increasing numbers, because that would require infinite time and infinite storage.

Comment: @Ghimbo21: Okay, so it looks like you could change the extension method to accept `IEnumerable<string>` as the first parameter rather than an array...

Comment: @Chetan: No, an input of 101 results is definitely not equivalent to infinite, just because only the first 100 results are tested. I could easily write code which will succeed with 101 elements but fail with an infinite sequence. Basically I suspect the point of this exercise is to investigate lazy evaluation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the purpose of this exercise is to investigate *lazy evaluation*.

Currently your method accepts a `string[]` and returns an `int[]` - but there's nothing in the question that says it *has* to do that.

If instead you were to write an extension method accepting an `IEnumerable<string>` and returning an `IEnumerable<int>`, then you could accept an infinite sequence of elements and return a corresponding infinite sequence of outputs, that is lazily evaluated: when the caller requests the next output element, you in turn request the next input element, process it, and yield an output. C# makes all of this quite straightforward with [*iterator blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators).

So I would expect a method like this:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<int> GetContainedNumbers(IEnumerable<string> source)
{
    foreach (string inputElement)
    {
        int outputElement = ...; // TODO: your logic here
        yield return output;
    }
}
```

Now to *test* this, you can either use iterator blocks again to generate *genuinely* infinite sequences, or you could test against an *effectively* infinite sequence using LINQ, e.g.

```cs
IEnumerable<string> veryLargeInput = Enumerable
    .Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    .Select(x => $"a{x}z");
```

The truly infinite version might be something like:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> infiniteSequence = GetInfiniteSequence();
...
private static IEnumerable<string> GetInfiniteSequence()
{
    int value = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return $"x{value}z";
        // Eventually this will loop round from int.MaxValue to
        // int.MinValue. You could use BigInteger if you really wanted.
        value++;
    }
}
```

When testing the result, you'll want to take the first 100 elements of the output. For example:

```cs
var input = GetInfiniteSequence(); // Or the huge Enumerable.Range
var output = input.GetContainedNumbers(); // This is still infinite
var first100Elements = output.Take(100).ToList();
// Now make assertions against first100Elements
```